# My nozzle is heating up even when it shouldnt

Tags: troubleshooting, heat-management, temperature, thermistor

I would like help with the printer. When I wanted to print yesterday, the display wouldn't start, so I restored it and everything worked. Then the motor that pushes the filament didn't want to move, so I cleaned it up a bit. When I wanted to print something, the bed started to heat up, like 120 °C in a few seconds. So, I quickly connected everything and the nozzle showed -15 °C degrees. Then I replaced the whole extruder, and when I turned it on, the temperature was displayed, but it rose within 2 seconds to 250 °C.

The printer is Artillery Genius Pro.

I tried a new cable to the extruder, and also a new firmware, but it didn't help.

I really don't know what to do anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The heaters (and power supply) aren't capable of heating that fast*, so what you've observed seems to be an error in measurement of the temperature, not a sudden increase in temperature. This can be caused by a faulty thermistor, faulty wiring to the thermistor, or something wrong on the controller board where the thermistor connects to the microcontroller.

I would first make sure all the connections are not loose, and in the right places. Swapping a thermistor connector with some other type of connector may be able to cause a problem like this; typically a few different things use the same 2-pin JST type connectors.

If all the connections are right and you already replaced the hotend assembly (which includes a new thermistor, unless you moved the old one), your board is likely damaged.

(*) Note that this still creates a potential heat/fire danger, because any heating that takes place won't be controlled by accurate measurements of the resulting temperature change! So don't operate it like this.